# Detect how many screens are used end on which screen a form must load VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I've searched the web and couldn't find much on the following questions:

1. How can i detect with vb.net how many screens i have (and which resolution they have).
2. How can i send out a identify monitor command (to know which number each screen has)
3. How can i (after detection) choose on which screen my form must open?

Can someone help me out?

In my case i have 4 screens but i have to choose from the main form on which screen i want to load a second form.

I found this on the web but this doesn't detect any screens:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim form As New Form

Dim screen As Screen

' We want to display a form on screen 1

screen = screen.AllScreens(1)

' Set the StartPosition to Manual otherwise the system will assign an automatic start position

form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual

' Set the form location so it appears at Location (100, 100) on the screen 1

form.Location = screen.Bounds.Location + new Point(100, 100)

' Show the form

form.ShowDialog(Me)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PrimaryScreen` and `AllScreens` properties are `Shared` so you access them on the `Screen` class, not an instance of the `Screen` class.  Check out this code:

```
Dim primaryScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen
Dim allScreens = Screen.AllScreens

For Each screen In allScreens
    Dim location = Point.Add(screen.Bounds.Location, New Size(100, 100))
    Dim text = screen.DeviceName

    If screen Is primaryScreen Then
        text &= " (Primary)"
    End If

    Using dialogue As New Form With {.Text = text,
                                     .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                                     .Location = location}
        dialogue.ShowDialog()
    End Using
Next
```

That should demonstrate how the screens are named, and so how you can determine which is which, and also how to position a form on a specific screen.  I just tested it on my four-monitor setup at work and it behaved as expected.

Comment: okay, i hace 4 screens, i found a way (that works) to detect how many screens are installed,,  but  how can i select on which screen my next form will open on fullscreen

Comment: I'm not sure why the code you originally had didn't work but the code I posted worked for me. All your screens are views on a single, large desktop surface. The `Location` of the form determines where on that one desktop your form appears.  The `Bounds` of each `Screen` represents the `Rectangle` that that screen displays of the one desktop.  If you set the `Location` of a form relative to the `Location` of that `Rectangle` then you can make the form appear on that physical screen, exactly as I have done in my code.

Comment: In order to choose the screen on which to display the form in the first place, you can get A `Screen` object from the `Screen.PrimaryScreen` property if you want the screen designated as the primary, or you can use the `DeviceName` property if you want to select one by number.  When I tested at work with four monitors and at home with 2, the display name was "\\.\DISPLAYN" where N was the number of the monitor in Windows Display properties. Note that the `AllScreens` list is NOT necessarily in that same order.